# swipe to get random core data Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, random

I would like to make an app that pics random facts from either a flat file and does it at random and any time i swipe to the right it shows me a new random fact from that file. Can anybody point me into the right direction or point out a tutorial? I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out!

I need to know if the file should be a sql file or core data
and how to generate it at random.

thank you

Comment: how many facts do you have to store?

Comment: http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2010/06/fetch-random-record-with-coredata.html have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You just need to break this down.

First you need a data structure you  can randomly pick from. 
NSArray
You can easily put NSDictionaries in an array.

Easy enough to sort an array. 
Easier still to get a random number from an array of indexes. 
You might add logic to exclude previously seen item. Or even all previously seen in a session.

Ok, next part. 
Swiping is a gesture. That means its tied to the UI. That means it is decoupled from the random pick logic. 
You just need to have a swipe gesture in your view or window invoke an IBAction method. 
That method calls the random pick method in your app controller.